# Infinite progress glitch in cn1

Tags: codenameone

Infinte progress icon rotates super fast for a couple of seconds before it rotates normal... How can I fix it?

https://youtu.be/FLrlWY8Evfw

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of CPU usage. The "super fast" speed just means we have more CPU available for rendering but if you take up CPU e.g. in processing a server response or connections you would see it in the amount of repaints we can do.

Even if you do these things off the EDT the performance of the progress indicator will be impacted.

Comment: Can't we do some adjustments or hacks to make the speed uniform? Since in native android or other development languages like react native & others, the inifinite progress or indicator works pretty good but in our cn1, it is too fast at the beginning...

Comment: I looked at the code and there might be something we can improve I made this commit which will hopefully resolve this https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/55c8bae40832fb1bf76ca55bb1dd8b73fcdc06c7

Comment: You can try using `setAngleIncrease` with a lower value. The default is 16.